# Convert columns in dataframe with comas into numeric data to plotting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, beautifulsoup

I'm new in the world of plotting in Python I started learning today doing a mini project by my own, I tried to scrape data and represent here's my code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

# Getting the HTML page
URL = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries"
pag_html = requests.get(URL).text

# Extracting data with BeautifulSoup.
soup = BeautifulSoup(pag_html, 'html.parser')

tabla = soup.find("table", id="main_table_countries_today")

datos_tabla = tabla.tbody.find_all("tr")

Lista = []

for x in range(len(datos_tabla)):
  values = [j.string for j in datos_tabla[x].find_all('td')]
  Lista.append(values)


df = pd.DataFrame(Lista).iloc[7: , 1:9]
nombre_columna = ["Pais", "Casos totales", "Nuevos Casos", "Muertes totales", "Nuevas Muertes", "Total Recuperados", "Nuevos Recuperados", "Activos"]
df.columns = nombre_columna



df.plot(x="Pais", y="Casos totales", kind ="barh")
plot.show()
```

The error it's giving me is: "TypeError: no numeric data to plot" I understand that this error is because  the column "Casos totales" is a string not a float.
I tried to convert the columns of my Dataframe into floats, but there's no way I got error from everywhere.
Does anyone have any idea how can I represent my DataFrame?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running the script, as you say the column "Casos Totales" is being interpreted as string due to the commas in the values. You can change this using `.str.replace(',','')` and then `.astype(float)`, right after renaming the column names in your dataframe:

```
df['Casos totales'] = df['Casos totales'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)


df.plot(x="Pais", y="Casos totales", kind ="barh")
plot.show()
```

And this plots the graph (although the visualization is quite poor, but that's another story)

Comment: No problem. I see that other columns have some other signs too, such as "+". You should follow the same technique replace it with nothing so it gets interpreted as a numeric type. Saludos a la distancia!